# css: create color overlay on top of youtube embed

Tags: css

I'm trying to add color overlay on top of a youtube embed video. I'm using vue-youtube-embed component to embed the video.

```css
.video-player {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 360px;
  width: 640px;
}

.color-overlay {
  height: 360px;
  width: 640px;
  background: black;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-player mx-auto">
  <div class="color-overlay">
    <youtube video-id="vT__WcbNWpY"></youtube>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `video-player` class is used to add rounded corners on the video. The `color-overlay` does not work as I wanted it and it shows nothing. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean it show's nothing? Do you want to have a transparent overlay over the video to show a thumbnail or something?

Comment: on the css, I set the background to black. therefore I was hoping, there would be a black background on top of the video. If it works, then I will set the opacity of the color. But right now, the black color doesn't even show up. @nadz

Comment: can you check if background color property of overlay is overriden by any other property in css?

Comment: The code you've shared renders the `color-overlay` as black.

Comment: @Dhara i've tried running it in playground, see here https://jsfiddle.net/05mdtyz6/2/ but it still doesn't work

Comment: @jade if you set your frame's height width little smaller than you can see your background. currently it is hiding due to the height and width of iframe.

Comment: @Dhara oh I see. But I want the color to be on top of the video. Is my `z-index` false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML, make the overlay div a sibling of `iframe`.
Then just use *absolute positioning* inside your common parent, like so:

```css
.video-player {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 360px;
  width: 640px;
}

.color-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-player mx-auto">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT__WcbNWpY&t=3s&ab_channel=OceanConservationNamibia" width="640" height="360"></iframe>
    <div class="color-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works, but I still have to set the width and height of the `color-overlay` same like the video size. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add overlay tag outside of div so it can consume all screen and will add overlay on screen. if you need only on iframe just add **color-overlay** div inside **video-player** div

```css
.color-overlay {
      height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.2;
    position: absolute;
}

.video-player {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 360px;
  width: 640px;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-overlay"></div>
<div class="video-player mx-auto">

  <div class="">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vT__WcbNWpY&t=3s&ab_channel=OceanConservationNamibia" width="600" height="300"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works as I expected! Much appreciated. :)

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept as an answer so it can help others easily.